# Would I need to reinstall OS after I inserted hard drive from one laptop to another

Tags: hard-drive, migration

The title is self-explanatory. I have two laptops: the first is as good as broken and the second lacks hard-drive. So I figured it's best to make them one by moving the hard-drive from one to another.
The question is, will I be forced to reinstall OS after that to make it work properly/at all?

Comment: If you're not going to use them as two different computers, you could try to make one and see how it goes

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu will work. But a few things you need to consider:

- the video card driver. If you go from nVidia to AMD or the other way around you should remove the driver on the old system and re-install it when the disk is inserted.
- going from 32-bit to a 64-bit system will work but a re-install might be better (so you get the benefit of 64-bit). The other way around (64->32)... just don't.

Answer (score 2):

In the general case, no. With Windows 8 I have observed that exchanging the hard drives from an Intel Core 2 Duo to an AMD Athlon X2 system will break it somehow. I also tried the Ubuntu and that booted just fine.

If you have a 32-bit version on the old system and more than 4 GB of RAM in the new system, it would make sense to install the 64-bit version of Ubuntu on the new system to use all the RAM, though.

Comment: Some 32-bit kernels can utilize more than 4 GB of memory (but a single process cannot get more than 4GB).  I do not know if hardware changes, trigger selection of such a kernel.

Comment: Indeed! The PAE kernels should do the trick. I assume that one has to install it manually.